# Work on multiple Sandboxes that belong to the same org. in Google Chrome

Tags: sandbox, chrome

I wish to test carry out testing in a Production environment and in the Sandbox environment using Google Chrome in different windows. Currently I have to use different browsers - (Firefox or Safari etc.) to test. Is there anyway or any Google Chrome Application that will allow me to run the Production org and Sandbox with just using Google Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use Google Chrome’s [multiple user feature](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en). When you switch the user, Chrome opens a new Chrome window, with entire different set of everything including cookies.

Answer (score 4):

As long as they are on different instances (the naX/csY part in na1.salesforce.com) you can work in multiple orgs simultaneously. Just remember to always visit login.salesforce.com and not to logout from one org.
When using chrome, this extension may help a big deal: [Chrome Salesforce.com Sandbox Favicon Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforcecom-sandbox-fav/nkfllgjejgfgcddfccnijhndhdmjkamf)

Comment: Also, I find Incognito mode helps a lot since the browsers will have different color schemes,  helping to differentiate which org you are in.

Comment: If they are on the same instance you can refresh the sandbox org (which will delete everything in it and refresh to what production has in it) and the instance may change or during a preview release window you can get the org to move instances if you really want it to be different.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Off's answer, you can use the [Chrome Incognito window](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464) to open up another instance of Chrome that doesn't share session details (Cookies) with any existing instance. As such, you can log into another sandbox regardless of it being on the same pod as another session you have open.